# Working with utf-8 files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Quite straight forward question. Is there a way to configure Eclipse to work with text files encoded with utf-8 with and without the BOM?

So far I've used eclipse with utf-8 encoding and it works, but when I try to edit a file generated by another editor that includes the BOM, Eclipse doesn't handle it properly, it 'shows an invisible character' at the begining of the file (the BOM). Is there a way to make Eclipse understand utf-8 encoded files with BOM?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both [bug 78455](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=78455) ("Provide an option to force writing a BOM to UTF-8 files") and [bug 136854](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=136854) don't leave much hope for such an option.

> **The support for encoding in the workspace is based on what is available from Java**.
>   For any given resource in the workspace, it is possible to obtain a charset string that can be used with any Java APIs that take charset strings.
>   Examples are:
>
> - '`US-ASCII`',
> - '`UTF-8`',
> - '`Cp1252`',
> - '`UTF-16`' (Big Endian, BOM inserted automatically),
> - '`UTF-16BE`' (Big Endian, BOM not inserted automatically),
> - '`UTF-16LE`' (Little Endian, BOM not inserted automatically).
>
> **For Java encodings, except for the 'UTF-16' encoding, BOMs are not inserted (when writing) or discarded (when reading) for free**.
>   Even if this is puzzling to end users, this is how all Java applications work.
>   **If applications want to support creating UTF-8 files with BOMs to match their users' expectations, they need to provide such capability on their own** (as neither Java nor the Resources model will help with that).
>   Eclipse does provide some improvements towards detecting BOMs, but not with generating or skipping them.