# Remove UTF-8 DOM in URL - JS & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, url, uploadify, byte-order-mark

I am having a problem with "strange" chars in URL.

I am using Uploadify script to upload files on server. I am getting a problem when I try onComplete load a preview image.

Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#file_upload').uploadify({
     'height'    : 30,
     'width'     : 100,
     'buttonImg' : '<?=base_url()?>style/images/buttons/button_dodaj_gray.png',
     'cancelImg' : '<?=base_url()?>style/js/uploadify/cancel.png',
     'wmode'     : 'transparent',
     'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
          if( response != "ERROR" )
          {
              var imageSrc = "";
              //imageSrc = "/ads_images_temp/";
              imageSrc = response;
              $('.image_container').html('<img src="<?=base_url()?>'+imageSrc+'"></img>');
          }
     },
     'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif',
     'displayData': 'percentage',
     'multi'     : false,
     'uploader'  : '<?=base_url()?>style/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
     'script'    : '/tools/upload/product/glavna',

     'auto'      : true
   });
});
</script>
```

The problem is in line: `$('.image_container').html('<img src="<?=base_url()?>'+imageSrc+'"></img>');`.

I don't get clean URL of image but I get this: `%EF%BB%BF768f32dd43cc1f90b79c83cceed57eb2.png`.

Filename: 768f32dd43cc1f90b79c83cceed57eb2.png

**UPDATE:**
My PHP file for reading image:

```
if ( !empty($_FILES) )
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = $temp_path;
                $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
                $config['max_size'] = 4000;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = true;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if( ! ($this->upload->do_upload("Filedata"))) // Napaka pri nalaganju slike
                {
                    //echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
                    echo "ERROR";
                }
                else // Vse OK, nadaljuj
                {
                    $img = $this->upload->data();

                    if($img['image_width'] > 650)
                    {
                        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                        $config['source_image'] = $img['full_path'];
                        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                        $config['width'] = 650;

                        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                        $this->image_lib->resize();
                    }

                    // Resize image    
                    $this->Product_model->resize_image($img['full_path'], $temp_path.'/crop_'.$img["raw_name"].$img["file_ext"], 160, 120);
                    $this->Product_model->resize_image($img['full_path'], $temp_path.'/crop_crop_'.$img["raw_name"].$img["file_ext"], 80, 60);

                    //$this->session->set_userdata("oddaja_oglasa_glavnaSlika",$img["raw_name"].$img["file_ext"]);

                    $imeSlike = $img["raw_name"].$img["file_ext"];

                    echo $imeSlike;
                }
            }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Chrome console screenshot: http://imageshack.us/f/818/uploadifychromeconsole1.png/

Regards, Mario

Comment: How are you reading the image in PHP?

Comment: @andyb: I have updated my first post..

Comment: Are you using http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html in your example?

Comment: @andyb: I am using that library, yes.

Comment: Sorry, can I see the _Network_ tab in Chrome so I can see the AJAX request and response. One thing to try is create a test PHP file that just returns a simple `echo` and call that from uploadify instead; so we can start to rule things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - JSON!:)

Echo in PHP:

```
    $json = array("name" => $imeSlike, "error" => 0);
    echo json_encode($json);
```

In JS:

```
...
'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
        eval("var obj1="+response);

        if( obj1.error == 0 )
        {
            $('.image_container').html('<img src="<?=base_url()?>ads_images_temp/crop_'+obj1.name+'"></img>');
        }
     },
...
```

Thank you all for your time and sharing solutions!

Regards, Mario

Answer (score 2):

`EF BB BF` is the UTF-8 representation of the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM). Something is saving or returning the UTF-8 encoded data with the *optional* BOM at the beginning.

Looks like it has been reported in the [uploadify forum](http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/1784/utf8-bom-in-response-parameter-of-oncomplete/p1).

**Edit**

OK, so the file that `echo $imeSlike` must have been saved with the BOM as the first 3 bytes. You need to configure your editor to **not** add the BOM when saving PHP files (or indeed any file).

As an alternative, if you are using Windows, a great editor for highlighting these sorts of encoding problems is [EditPad](http://editpadpro.com/download.html#trial) (although there are plenty of others in which you can configure whether the BOM is added). You can turn off the BOM in the *Options*. Or you could try saving the file as ASCII encoding which will also remove the BOM. However, depending on the content of your PHP this might not be a practical solution.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.My PHP code: `echo $img["name"];`  Image name is encrpyted with md5 so there isn't any strange chars in image name...

Comment: @Puzo: in your text editor, uncheck the "Save UTF-8 BOM" option (however it's called).

Comment: @Puzo: Not sure about Zend Studio but, apparently, in regular Eclipse [you cannot choose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905582/working-with-utf-8-files-in-eclipse/2905998#2905998).

Comment: An OSS alternative to EditPad is Notepad++

Comment: @andyb: Thanks for your informations and solution. Is there any PHP function that remove BOM from string? I am already searching but without luck..

Comment: Maybe http://blog.philipp-michels.de/?p=32 but the correct fix is to simply save your PHP file that processes the upload without the BOM.

Comment: I just tried this function, but no luck: `function removeBOM($str=""){
        if(substr($str, 0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) {
                $str=substr($str, 3);
        }
        return $str;
}`

Comment: @andyb: I just opened file in EditPad Pro 7 and save it and upload it back to server. There is stil BOM in string...

Comment: Did you change the BOM option first? You can see if the BOM is present by switching to Hex mode (Ctrl + H). If the first 3 characters are `ef BB BF` then the BOM is still being added. _Options_ -> Configure File Types -> Encoding (tab) -> uncheck "Write a byte order mark...". Then re-save the file.

Comment: Do I need to remove the BOM from a file only to handle the upload or from file where is JS and HTML ? I even open file in Notepad++, Convert to UTF-8 Without BOM and still nothing... When I open the file in EditPad and switch to Hex mode, there can not be found `EF BB BF.`

In EditPad is this option already unchecked...

Comment: What is the `/tools/upload/product/glavna` script? The BOM is at the start of the `response` coming back from that script.

Comment: This is a controller. `upload` is a controler, `product` is a method and `glavna` is parameter. This is in file `upload.php`. This "script" handle the upload process..

Comment: Right so `upload.php` is the end-point for _uploadify_ and it is that file that responds with the filename. You are completely sure that `upload.php` does not have a BOM? Since that is the _only_ possibility I can think of, other than just removing the first 3 bytes in the `complete` callback (which I do not recommend as it might break if or when the BOM is correctly removed).

Comment: OK, no BOM in that file :-) If that is the file being used in the upload and there is nothing else `echo`ing before the filename then I am running out of ideas!

Comment: One `echo` is before but this echo is in case if there is error while uploading file to server.. Is that `echo` problematic? Yes that file is used...

Comment: Last idea (for now). Can you open the _Console_ in Chrome and see the exact response that is echoed back to JavaScript from upload.php? Could you edit the question and add any finding/screenshots please. I am guessing that you will see the BOM + filename in the response text.

Comment: I did update my first post... I just saw in HTML that: `ďťż<!DOCTYPE html><head>`.